What is the role for each of these AC coupling components?
I'd like to learn more about the RP2040 PWM Audio AC coupling circuit found in figure 22 in this document.
Figure 22. Schematic section showing the Analogue PWM audio circuit

Even though I understand the general purpose of AC coupling, can someone clarify the specific role for each of the components placed after the logic buffers output in the circuit? (It appears to me that the circuit is duplicated for each of the stereo channels, so I'm referring to R1, C7, R3, C14 and R7).

A PWM signal swinging between 0 and a positive peak can be considered as the sum of an AC signal and a DC offset. DC offset is the avg (mean) value which is equal to the duty-cycle of the PWM signal times the signal peak:

Img from my answer here.
So if you feed this PWM to a low-pass filter with low-enough cut-off frequency, you can get rid of the pulses and sharp edges (pretty much) and end up with the mean value. This method is also known as "PWM DAC" which means having an instantaneous DC voltage by adjusting the duty cycle.
If you have a PWM with a varying duty-cycle then after filtering you can have a varying signal at the output. See the brown curve below:

ImgSrc
Now this is what R1-R3-C7 network is for. They form a divider as well as a low-pass filter with a cut-off frequency of ~23 kHz (Take the Thevenin equivalent of 100R and 220R, and calculate the cut-off using the result and 100n capacitance).
C14 is needed for AC coupling because you don't want a DC voltage to appear across the headphone speaker (1). So the C14 removes the DC component of the resultant varying audio signal. Plus, C14 and the load resistance forms a high-pass filter. For example, for a 32-Ohm speaker we can expect a roll-off at around 100 Hz.
(1) Note that both the L and the R outputs are single ended. If the outputs were differential then the AC coupling caps (C14 and C15) wouldn't be needed as the DC offsets of both ends of the differential would be cancelled out.

Thank you so much for your thorough answer! It helps a lot. Sometimes I see AC coupling with even fewer components. Am I understanding right that a minimum requirement for AC coupling is to use only a highpass RC filter?

@Erik AC coupling means isolating in DC or low frequencies. Usually a single capacitor is enough. But remember, the capacitor and the input impedance of the next circuit still form a CR high-pass filter. Take a look at this, for example. The R1-R2 brings a DC bias and you don't want that DC to pass to the signal source. So there's a coupling capacitor. With that, in the direction from the amplifier to the source, the DC is blocked. Perfect. But, in the direction from single source to the amplifier, ...

... parallel equivalent of R1-R2 and the coupling cap form a CR high-pass filter. So the DC on the signal source (if there's any) along with some low-frequency content coming from the signal source will be rejected.

Multiple components do multiple things.
And this isn't simply just AC coupling any more. It's much more than that.
R1 220 ohms rises the digital buffer IC output impedance, i.e. it limits the current in case of someone accidentally short circuits the output. Which will happen during plugging and unplugging. R1 also limits the current to C7. So even with a short circuit on headphone connector, R1 limits current to 15mA which the chip can handle well without being damaged.
R1 220 ohms and R3 100 ohms form a voltage divider. The buffer IC outputs 3.3 Vpp which is generally too high for 3.5mm audio output, if you use headphones or connect to amplifier line in. R1 and R3 divide the 3.3 Vpp output to about 1.03 Vpp which should be an OK value.
The 100nF capacitor C7 forms a low pass RC filter, but it does not only depend on R1 but both R1 and R2 of the divider. And things after it but we can ignore them for now. The output impedance of the resistor divider R1 & R3 driving the capacitor C7 is about 69 ohms, making the RC lowpass 3dB cutoff as high as 23 kHz.
Then you have the actual 47uF AC coupling capacitor C14. For a 50% duty PWM the DC bias of the lowpass filtered audio is about 0.5V. The DC biased AC audio goes in and out comes AC audio with any DC bias set by the rest of the circuit.
The 1k8 resistor R7 is a DC load for that ties the output of capacitor to a bias of 0V, i.e. no DC bias, so it sets the output bias. Basically it's there to set DC bias to 0V even if nothing is connected, so that the DC bias does not discharge through the amplifier or headphones when they are plugged in. It also forms an RC highpass filter of about 2 Hz with the AC coupling capacitor, if the effect of voltage divider source impedance and the load is not considered.
Then there is the audio output connector. Any load put there will affect any circuit parameters calculated with simple methods, but an amplifier is a high impedance load so it can be ignored and headphones may be 32 ohms which is a lot, so the amplitude will go down more and the lowpass cutoff will be higher in the order of above 100 ohms.
This circuit can be easily simulated how it works.
